# starting slideshow from the specified image index

Tags: slideshow, jquery-dialog, galleria

i'm using Galleria slideshow on my web page. I want to start a slideshow from the specified index. In code I pass a parameter to a JavaScript function and in this functions I wrote a line Galleria.configure('show', index); So my function is

```
function imgIndex(i) {
    index = i; 
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    Galleria.configure('show', index);
}
```

Also Galleria is in a popup jquery-dialog in the page. The HTML is

```
<div id="dialog" title="Galleria dialog">
<div id="galleria" style="float: left;  width: 100%; background-color: #000000;">
<script src="famous/list_images.php"></script>
<script>
  Galleria.run('#galleria', {
  dataSource: data,
  transition: 'slide',
  transitionSpeed: 800,
  responsive:true,
  thumbnails: false,
  clicknext: true,
  autoplay: true,
  height: 0.5625 
});
</script>
</div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when I first time click on image slideshow starts in a popup dialog on the specified index. But when I close the dialog and want to start it again from the other image it seems that Galleria doesn't react to this and continues from the image where it was last time.

Thank you for your help.